# Best practice for implementing "tab support" in facebook App

Tags: php, facebook

I started to stumble Facebook App development and can't get my Application to be added as a tab in the fan page, I think my Application should have a support for being able to be installed as a tab? what is the best practice the one I found on docs - Profile.setFBML method, but they are saying that it will be removed soon, can't get what is the alternative =) , so how should I implement the tab support for my App

Comment: Or in other words what is alternative for depricated Profile.setFBML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a page which returns correct FBML page(FBML+allowed HTML tags), then set address of that page in your application settings in tab url. like this:

http://yoursite.com/facebook/profiletab